# SES email not sending

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES service to send email with verified test email address in SES and used same for the Source.

I am trying to send email to other email address but not able to send it's giving me error "Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1".

Reference for code to send email: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

I have read in aws documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html) "If your account is still in the Amazon SES sandbox, you also must verify every recipient email address except for the recipients provided by the Amazon SES mailbox simulator" this is the reason or some settings needed?

Please let me know if anybody knows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,AWS initially puts your SES account in Sandbox mode where you need to verify both Sender and recipient addresses.

You can follow the below link and change the account status to Production:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

This will ask you a couple of questions, once this is done, you no longer to verify recipient email address (To,cc,bcc), however From/Sender email address is also required to be verified in SES(in both production and sandbox mode).

Answer (score 0):

We also need to make sure we have those verified email addresses in the same region you have initialized AWS SES SDK.